# Can hot-plugging an HDMI cable damage the HDMI port?

Tags: computers, electronics

I found [this site](http://www.hdtvsupply.com/hdmi-problems.html) on the Internet saying something to that effect:

> Warning!!.....Never connect and disconnect HDMI cables and equipment while your devices are powered on (hot plugging cables). The hdmi cables carries a low DC voltage while connected. You will damage your equipment and the HDMI Distribution equipment while hot-plugging cables which will not be replaced under the 1 year manufacturers warranty. Only use the Switched Mode Power supply supplied with the HDMI Equipment since replacing the power adapter might damage your equipment if incorrect voltage is supplied to the equipment.

Comment: This [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/440959/is-hdmi-hot-pluggable) says that HDMI is designed to be hot pluggable. Of course, that doesn't mean that a poorly designed device can't be damaged.

Comment: I don't think this question meets the standards of notability. Something your friend said isn't notable.

Comment: @Avi a friend saying something doesn't preclude it fr being notable.

Comment: No, but the burden of proof is on the person asking the question to demonstrate that it is notable.

Comment: @Avi No. Demonstration of notability is not required, simply notability. Until a few days ago, I also thought that demonstration of notability was required, but as per the conversation starting [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12646766#12646766), it is not.

Comment: @Articuno if there's any doubt that a claim is notable (such as in this case) then a demonstration of notability is required. The requirement for a reference to a notable claim is also useful, in that referenced claims are often more specific, and thus more answerable.

Comment: @Avi I found a link on the Internet claiming something to that effect, see my edit.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Not anymore. See the discussion following from [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12648625#12648625). It's only required that the claim *be* notable, not that it be demonstrated.

Comment: @Articuno No. One mod's passing opinion in chat doesn't change policy (and I think you're over-interpreting that opinion anyway). If you want to change the policy, take it to meta.

Comment: @ene we'll clarify meta after discussion, that said: harassing every questioner who doesn't bring an example about notability is clearly *not* what was ever intended. The burden of verifying notability is up to the community. Before asking for notability samples, let's do a quick search.

Comment: @Avi no, the burden of proof is on us to google a claim before asking for notability...

Comment: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/1492/96

Answer (score 8):

The Hot-Plug-Detection feature is part of the HDMI protocol. All data-lines are quiet until a hotplug-event is detected via the physical pin 19. A handshake then negotiates a real connection:

> The HPD (Hot-Plug-Detect) feature is a communication mechanism between a source and a sink device that makes the source device aware that it has been connected/disconnected to/from the sink device. When an HDMI cable is inserted between the two devices, the resulting hot-plug detection instantiates a start-up communication sequence.

So, unless we're talking about massive static discharge - which should be prevented by opto-isolation if we're talking about a proper implementation - it is safe, even safer than USB which applies 5 V of Vcc right away without any prior negotiation.

Source: http://www.ni.com/white-paper/12680/en/

Edit: Regarding the physical USB connectors I should point out that the data- and Vcc-/mass connectors are not of the same length. If you plug it in, mass and power is applied before the data lines are physically attached. This works good enough for most applications.

Comment: Thanks. So it never happens in practice? You don't statistically increase any risk of damage to the HDMI port at all, for any kind and any quality of HDMI cable, by hot-plugging your HDMI cable vs. turning one of the devices off, and then plugging it?

Comment: No, I  wouldn't claim that it never happens. I don't have any statistical data for this, just the words of your friend radio technician. But I can imagine that regular failure rates apply; after market introduction you see a higher failure rate ("infant mortality"), then over the regular lifetime an even distribution of failures and at the end of life a higher failure rate due to wear out. Also note that HDMI is now for about 10 years of the market so you will notice 1st and 2nd generation products to fail a lot by now. Anecdotal evidence could be interpreted as"fails too often".

Comment: I have the impression it is rare, still a few people claim that it destroyed their video card. Do you think it is possible to send the card back for warranty in these cases?